# assign value to list of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

g is a list of list, I use it as a 2d array.
But when I assign values to g[i][j], it doesn't work.

Here is my code.

```
m=3
n=4 
g=[[0]*n]*m
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        g[i][j]=i
        print(g[i][j])

print(g)
```

the output is

```
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
[[2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
g=[[0]*n]*m
```

is the problem. Try this instead:

```
g=[[0]*n for _ in range(m)]
```

The difference between these two approaches is that, the former is a list of `m` items, each is the *same* list of `n` zeros. But the latter, is a list of `m` items that each is a *different* list of `n` zeros.